# Single selected item on recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to highlight onmy one item on my recyclerview when user click. But I have an unexpected behavior.

When I click on one item, the adapter logs me that that one is selected and hightlighted. But when I scroll, I see that there are other items highlighted.

Any help on that issue will be really appreciate.

My codes:

My Adapter

```
public class ChooseRecipientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooseRecipientViewHolder> {


 @Override
public ChooseRecipientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_recipients_item, null);
    ChooseRecipientViewHolder cv = new ChooseRecipientViewHolder(this.context, v);
    return cv;
}

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ChooseRecipientViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    RecipientItem settingsRecipients = recipientItems.get(position);
    settingsRecipients.holder = holder;

    holder.title.setText(settingsRecipients.title);

    holder.recipient = recipients.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (selectedItem < 0) {
                selectedItem = position;
                holder.isSelected = true;
                holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
                holder.title.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_background));
            } else if (holder.isSelected) {
                selectedItem = -1;
                holder.isSelected = false;
                holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                holder.title.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
                ChooseRecipientActivity.recipient = null;

            } else {
                if (getItem(selectedItem).holder != null) {
                    getItem(selectedItem).holder.isSelected = false;
                    getItem(selectedItem).holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                    getItem(selectedItem).holder.title.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
                    selectedItem = position;
                    holder.isSelected = true;
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
                    holder.title.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_background));
                    ChooseRecipientActivity.recipient = holder.recipient;

                } 
            }
        }
    });


}
```

My ViewHolder

```
public class ChooseRecipientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


public String id;
public Context context;
public ImageView leftImageView;
public TextView title;
public boolean isSelected = false;
public Recipient recipient;
public View itemView;


public ChooseRecipientViewHolder(final Context context, View view) {
    super(view);
    this.context = context;
    this.leftImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftIcon);
    this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    itemView = view;

    }
}
```

A screenshot:

[Highligted issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTvsu.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to reset your `ViewHolder` selected status if the row isn't selected.

```
if(selected) {
    setRowColour();
} else {
    resetColourToDefaults();
}
```

This is extremely important, because `RecyclerView` will reuse `ViewHolder` rows as you scroll up and down. A reused row will retain the formatting that was applied to it previously.

Comment: Yes, it is what I do in the last else in onClick() method in the adapter.
I reset the old selected and highlight the new one.

Comment: That won't help you in the onClick method. It needs to be in the `onBindViewHolder` method itself.